# How can I fix Android Studio build errors in .../user/.gradle.cache/...?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Android Studio build fail to errors in .../user/.gradle.cache/...

When i sync the project it work fine but when i run it i have this errors.
The errors is pointed to a line of code in .gradle file, when i try to delete this line, in the next build the error switch to next line.

[image]

[image]

WHAT I TRIED:
inspect code DONE

clean up code DONE

delete .../user/.gradle/.cache/... DONE

Downgrade/Upgrade gradle DONE

build on another pc DONE

Comment: It seems like there are issues with your value.xml file. Please check the file. According to the screenshots, one issue is that the color is not defined properly and the other issue is that the naming tag is incorrect.

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures